# Meaning of evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

What does this JavaScript snippet mean? The `(evt)` part is so confusing; `evt` is not a boolean. How it works?

```
function checkIt(evt) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
        
    }
```

Comment: if `evt` is set ie not `undefined` or `null` or `false` then that expression uses `evt` or else it picks up the `window event`

Comment: cause evt ? evt : window.event is more confusing...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event` is just the [inline `if` syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a). It's equivalent to this code:

```
if (evt) {
    evt = evt;
} else {
    evt = window.event;
}
```

If `evt` is truthy, `evt` will be left alone. If `evt` isn't truthy, it will be replaced with `window.event`.

Comment: @amesh: Right, that's why I said *truthy*. If `evt` isn't `null`, `undefined`, `NaN` (I think), `0` or `false`, it's considered truthy. Basically, if `evt` has been set already, it's truthy.

Answer (score 3):

It's for event listeners.

IE6-IE8 used a totally different event method than the W3C standard.

When an event fires, a W3C-standard browser will pass an event object in the callback:

```
function keyPressed (e) { /* do stuff with e */ }
```

In your case, it's `keydown` (or something else using `keyCode`).
IE didn't support this, instead it had `window.event` which was updated every time an event happened.

So your function is checking to see if an object was passed into it:

```
evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
// does `evt` exist, and is it anything but '', 0, false, null, undefined, NaN
// yes: evt = itself (W3C)
// no: evt = window.event (IE6-8)
```

Then the code asks if `evt.which` exists, to try to figure out where to get the keyCode from.
`evt.keyCode` is what you should be using for modern browsers, in the case of `keydown` and `keyup`.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment expressions like that are evaluated from *right to left*, so this means:

- if `evt` has a *truthy* value, assign this value back to `evt`
- if not, assign the value of `window.event` regardless of its content to `evt`

Answer (score 1):

It means: if the `evt` parameter has a value then keep the value, if it doesn't have a value then use `window.event` instead.

The `?` and ':' symbols are part of the ternary if operator:

```
var w = x ? y : z;
```

so above you assign either `y` or `z` to `w` depending on whether `x` is considered to be a true or false value.

If the `checkIt` function was called without passing in an `evt` argument i.e. `checkIt()` then inside the function the `evt` variable will have the value of `undefined` which is treated as `false` within an if condition.