# jQuery - Function Parameters

Tags: jquery

I read the following, but still want to discuss....
[Meaning of evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635142/meaning-of-evt-evt-evt-window-event)

//Would evt need to be passed because it is not used in the function??? --- Trying to get my mind wrapped around this jQuery stuff.

A)

```
$('#' + _ids.btnPrintServiceCode).on('click', function (evt) {
        alert('Hello World')
    });
```

OR

B)

```
$('#' + _ids.btnPrintServiceCode).on('click', function () {
        alert('Hello World')
    });
```

Comment: Side note: You can call `evt` whatever you want. You can call it `function(IAmMoojjoo)` and it will still work: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/sZEuC/1/).  Also start using [`console.log()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it) rather than `alert()`; it is a better tool for debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to pass the `evt` if it is not used, it is optional. However having it won't create an issue.

You basically pass `evt` if you need to listen to the event. Say you want to prevent the default behaviour of some elements, so you need `evt` here.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('a').on('click', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the default behaviour of that element
    alert('Hello World');
});

$('input').keyup(function(e){ //here we need to pass e as we are using e to get the keyCode that was pressed
   if(e.keyCode == 8 )
   {
        alert('test');
    }
});
```

Comment: So does it hurt anything to have it.   I am picking up work from another developer?

Comment: The `event` object is *always* passed to your function.  You don't have to add a parameter for it.

Comment: So why would it be written like A)?   Looking to understand this better.  Thank you ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way. Lets say i have this function:

```
function foo (bar) {
    alert("worky");
}
foo("foobar"); // worky
```

Since inside the function i'm never actually using `bar`, i can simplify the function by removing `bar` from the parameter list.

```
function foo () {
    alert("worky");
}
foo("foobar"); // worky
```

both will have the same result. The same is true with your event binding. Since you are never using `evt`, there is no reason for you to pass it to the function, however it won't hurt anything if you do anyway.

If the previous developer always passed `evt` to event handler callbacks, you should continue to do so to keep the code consistent, but that's entirely up to you.

Comment: Awesome, that did it...  Thanks ---- LIGHTBULB... DING DING DING